# Feed access control

Tags: security, authentication, rss, feed, atom-feed

Is there a sensible setup for private feeds (rss or atom) with some sort of security and authentication?

The application in question creates "private news" with sensible information for each user and the request is to present these news via feeds. Only the user may gain access and read his news and should be able to subscribe to then.

Answer (score 1):

Most sites that I have seen provide something like this either use HTTP Authentication or an obscured URL (like a GUID).